# Python dictionary counting

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
a={}
a['A']=1
a['B']=1
a['C']=2
```

I need to output the following

```
1 has occurred 2 times
2 has occurred 1 times
```

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: I tried   print [len(v) for k,v in d]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily (and efficiently) done with [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is designed to (unsurprisingly) count things:

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 2}
>>> collections.Counter(a.values())
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1})
```

This gives you a dictionary-like object that can trivially be used to generate the output you want.

Comment: it's a good practice to accept an answer by clicking on the tick next to  it when you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter

a = {}
a["A"] = 1
a["B"] = 1
a["C"] = 2

c = Counter(a.values())

c
=> Counter({1: 2, 2: 1})
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Comment: Re-read the question, this isn't what is wanted. The asker wants to count the number of times each value appears.

Comment: This answer exactly does what OP asked for.